# Gay or neutral equivalent to Casanova

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, obscure-terms

I've been searching for a bit to find something that fits this.

The closest I could find was Paramour which is more neutral, but it's still not exactly the same. I was wondering if there was a term that fit the bill here.

On the [dictionary page](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Casanova) for casanova, everything relates to men interested in women besides "philanderer" which really has more of a strictly "cheating" aspect to the name over Casanova which has a passionate about love aspect to the term.

I'm asking because I'm trying to include it in the title of a project I'm working on.

Sample sentence: "The man wooed many people, as he was quite the _____".

Comment: All you have to do is look at the synonyms and related words on this Merriam Webster entry: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Casanova     You can then click on each one and read their definitions.  If none of those words suit your purpose, then you can update your question with why they aren't quite right.

Comment: I recommend you read the page on single word requests and update your tags to include it.  You will need to show what research you've already done and include an example sentence showing how you will use the word.  For more information on single word requests, read this page here: https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info

Comment: I thought my question cleared it up, but the synonyms I find are entirely directed towards men interested in women. With the exception of philanderer, however that doesn't really include the "passionate for love" aspect that Casanova has.

I'll update it to include a sentence though, sorry about that. New to this all.

Comment: It would help if you included in your question something like "I found these words: A, B, and C. But they aren't quite what I'm looking for. They all suggest a man interested in women."  That way people won't suggest words you've already researched and decided didn't match what you want.

Comment: I think the update I included should fit the bill better.

Answer (score 1):

My two recommendations are romancer and seducer.  They are both gender neutral and do not imply a sexual orientation.

[**1. Romancer**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/romancer)

> 2 : one that romances

[Romance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/romances)

> transitive verb
>   1 : to try to influence or curry favor with especially
>   by lavishing personal attention, gifts, or flattery
>   2 : to carry on a love affair with

[**2. Seducer**](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=Dictionary#dobs=seducer)

> a person who entices someone into sexual activity.

^ Sorry, that definition comes from google. ^

[From the Collins Dictionairy](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/seducer)

> A seducer is someone, usually a man, who seduces someone else.

[Seduce](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seducer)

> 3 : to carry out the physical seduction of : entice to sexual
>   intercourse

Depending on if the person in question was more romantically inclined or more sexually inclined, you could choose one of these two words.

Answer (score 0):

***charmer***

> He was quite the *charmer*.

The best definition I found is from the urban dictionary -- sorry!

> a real sauve guy who knows how to talk to and get the ladies.

It doesn't have to be a guy, and the charming person doesn't need to be a lady, though.

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/charmer  or   https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/charmer